# Efficient Text Search for Large Term List: Python vs PostgreSQL vs Elasticsearch

Tags: python, postgresql, elasticsearch, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have a list containing terms that vary in length from 1 to 10 words, with approximately 500,000 entries. My goal is to search for these terms in a long text (converted from a PDF, typically 1.5 to 2 pages long). I need to perform the searches not only as exact matches but also using fuzzy (e.g., the term 'Lionel Messi' should match 'Lionel Mesi' in the text) and near options (e.g., the term 'Lionel Messi' should match 'Lionel J. Messi' in the text).

I aim to solve this problem in near real-time (1-2 second). I've tried using trie data structures and parallelization, but especially when the fuzzy aspect comes into play, the large size of the list and the PDF length lead to long processing times (about 30 seconds).

How should I approach this problem?

1. Can I handle it on the fly with Python libraries (using parallelization, trie structures, etc.)?
2. Are there features in PostgreSQL that support such searches?
3. Should I use a framework like Elasticsearch?"

Answer (score 1):

postgres offers native full-text search capabilities like https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

and there are also extensions like the recent https://docs.paradedb.com/blog/introducing_bm25
or https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector that work on vectors generated (f.e) by LLMs.

Comment: thanks for your response while i am not sure that PostgreSQL can handle that kind of search under 1-2 seconds. Is there any benchmark for this? And the second question, generally fuzzy searches are conducted based on two different terms like <"Lionel Messi", "Lion Mesi">. But in this case, I am looking for a term e.g. "Lionel Messi", in the long text. So this could also may have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Selam Batuhan, Elasticsearch [fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) search can handle this query near real-time. In fact, this is the main reason why Lucene, Elasticsearch or Opensearch exist.

Have you indexed your data in elasticsearch and measured time it took for a `Lionel Messi` search?

Here is a good article that explain the Damerau-Levenshtein distance. https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- Elasticsearch, Typesense, etc. can definitely give you this. You will need to manage them, though, which is a separate system.
- For Postgres, I would recommend pg_bm25: https://github.com/paradedb/paradedb/tree/dev/pg_bm25. It's free and benchmarks show this type of search takes ~30ms. You can see them here: https://github.com/paradedb/paradedb/blob/dev/benchmarks/README.md#pg_bm25 Disclaimer: I work on pg_bm25.
- You can get surprisingly far with Postgres tsvector. I don't know if you can get your 1-2second search for this much data, but you can try and see. That's pretty low overhead.
- Lastly, there's a tool called ZomboDB which allows interoperating Postgres and Elasticsearch. If you really want to use both, it's probably you best bet to streamline your workflow :)